# How to access parameter attribute inside .each?

Tags: jquery, each

I have some dynamically inserted inputs, and I'm using `.each()` to access them.

html:

```
<div id="filter">
    <input type="hidden" data-car="H car 1" data-img="http://dummyimage.com/117x117/000/ffffff.jpg&text=hyundai%202">
    <input type="hidden" data-car="W car 2" data-img="http://dummyimage.com/117x117/000/ffffff.jpg&text=wolks%202">
    <input type="hidden" data-car="P car 3" data-img="http://dummyimage.com/117x117/000/ffffff.jpg&text=peugeot%202">
</div>
```

I know I can access the attribute this way:

```
$('#filter input').each(function(i,j){
    console.log($('#filter input:eq('+i+')').attr('data-car'));
});
```

I know I can access the attribute this way:

```
console.log($('#filter input:eq('+i+')').attr('data-car'));
```

But I'm trying to access this way and it's not working:

```
console.log(j.attr('data-car'))
```

Is it possible to access the attribute using something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
$('#filter input').each(function(i, j){
    console.log($(j).data('car'));
});
```

jQuery has a [.data() method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) for that, and you should remember to wrapp `j` so it can access jQuery's methods, like: `$(j).data('car')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#filter input').each(function() {
   console.log($(this).attr('data-car'));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use

```
$(this).attr('data-car'));
```

Comment: not really sure why this was marked as wrong other than the fact that the comment did not have the entire code block in it.

Comment: A better way to answer this would be to show your proposed answer in the context of the original question's code.

Comment: Fair, and I do see why the above answer should be selected. I just did not understand why I was told my answer is not useful. Learning opportunity I suppose